# Are Wargames Research Group rules still available?

Tags: wargames-research-group

I used to use Wargames Research Group rules, mainly for modern warfare (post-WWII) wargames. Does anyone know if they are still available, or maybe a more recent update of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are still available, though free versions may be hard to track down. The best place to start would be [WRG's own website](http://www.wrg.me.uk/WRG.net/index.html), though copies are for sale on Amazon and elsewhere.

Comment: The latest version of DBA 3.0 is a nice improvement with a shift to base width measurements so allowing for smaller bases and tables if required.